# Woocommerce altered my homepage, and I can't figure out how to revert it

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, homepage, revisions

(I'm not sure if this is specific to Woocommerce or not, since the solution may be a general Wordpress process.. if it is I will delete and move to the wordpress forum)

I added Woocommerce to an existing site with the Astra theme. My site already had a nice homepage. The shop was to be reached from a menu. Woocommerce installed fine, and I decided to configure its settings. It quickly prompted me to create a 'custom homepage', and I clicked 'ok', assuming this homepage was for the 'shop' page, and not the homepage of my entire site.

Well, it changed the sites existing homepage, and when I tried to change back, using revisions, the pages theme seems to be gone, and a lot of the content(images and text) are missing and now unstructured(html and css seems all messed up or gone). I feel like there surely must be a way to simply undo this one click of a button? There wasn't even an 'are you sure?' prompt. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your home page may have gotten borked in this process. I can't think of a way to fix it aside from rolling back to before you made the new home page. You should be able to contact your host and see if they can roll you back from a DB back up. It sounds like when your updated the home page options may have been set in the customizer or some where else and that's more than likely what's breaking the display on your old home page.

So sadly, rolling back might be the best option. It would mean you would lose all current progress, which is no fun. It's possible I'm wrong and maybe someone else will correct me, but if I were in your shoes that's where I would start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If this is the case, that's really ridiculous. It was way too easy to put hours of work in the toilet. Yikes.